# Poisson Event After Time Interval

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

So I have this Poisson Problem that I'm struggling with, and the basis is that you have a server that fails once every four hours (so the average is 1/4 of a crash per hour).
The question that I'm really struggling with Is:
"What is the probability of a third system crash happening after the first 8 hours".
I have no idea how to solve it since it doesn't specify a closed interval.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the question is asking the probability that the third crash happens after the $8$ hour mark (which is to say, it does not happen before the 8 hour mark), this is just the probability that two or fewer crashes occur in the first eight hours. So there's your closed interval.

The number of crashes $N$ in the first eight hours is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda=2,$ so you just need to compute the probability of two or fewer crashes, $P(N\le 2).$

Comment: So in my calculations it would work out to something like 67% right?Thank you! EDIT: By the way isn't P(N<=2) equal to P(N<3)?

Comment: Yes, and yes.  .